# Applying box-shadow to tabs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply a box-shadow to tabs. The shadow should spread in every direction.
I'd like to have the tab and the label in white so they appear as a homogeneous surface.
My issue is that the shadow of the bottom tab element spreads to the label making the label look grayish and the border becomes visible.

```css
:root {
  --box-shadow: 
      0 0.6px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.028),
      0 1.3px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04),
      0 2.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
      0 4.5px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06),
      0 8.4px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072),
      0 10px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

body {
  background: #eee;
}
.tabs {
  margin: 5rem;
  width: 20rem;
}
.label {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 33%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
}
.tab {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
<div class="label">
  tab 1
</div>
<div class="tab">
lorem ipsum  
</div>
</div>
```

The desired result should look more or less like this, except the shadow should spread to the top as well (i.e.positive y axis).

```css
:root {
  --box-shadow: 
      0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02),
      0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.028),
      0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.035),
      0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.042),
      0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
      0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07); 
}

body {
  background: #eee;
}
.tabs {
  margin: 5rem;
  width: 20rem;
}
.label {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 33%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
}
.tab {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
<div class="label">
  tab 1
</div>
<div class="tab">
lorem ipsum  
</div>
</div>
```

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a bit of a hacky way to do it, but it works.

So first off, I'm adding `position: relative` and `z-index: 1` to the `.tab` class to put it on top of the label so the label's box shadow doesn't show on top of the tab.

Second, I'm putting a pseudo-element `::after` on top of the label. To do this, I put `position: relative` on the `.label` class and then set up the following element:

```
.label::after
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: attr(data-content);
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

So to walk through this, it's got 100% width and height to fill the `.label`'s width and height, with the same padding as you had previously included in the `.label` and `box-sizing: border-box` to make it maintain the correct width and height. The background of course is white to match the background of the plain `.label`, and the `position` is set to `absolute` with top and left of 0 to put it directly on top of the label. The `z-index` is set to 2 so it renders on top of the box shadow from the `.tab` below it.

Finally, I set the content of the `::after` to `attr(data-content)` so you can set the text inside the pseudo element to whatever you want in the HTML. It should match the text inside the `.label` itself so they are the same size and the cast box-shadow is the correct size.

```
<div class="label" data-content="tab 1">
```

Here's the full snippet.

```css
:root {
  --box-shadow: 
      0 0.6px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.028),
      0 1.3px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04),
      0 2.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
      0 4.5px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06),
      0 8.4px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072),
      0 10px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

body {
  background: #eee;
}
.tabs {
  margin: 5rem;
  width: 20rem;
}
.label {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 33%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
  position: relative;
}

.label::after
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: attr(data-content);
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tab {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
<div class="label" data-content="tab 1">
  tab 1
</div>
<div class="tab">
lorem ipsum  
</div>
</div>
```